# Review queue breakdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

As I click on the Review on top header, but I get this error page (see screenshot).

I think Review Queue is breakdown.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops, my fault - a bad SQL query change affected this - a fix is building out now.

Comment: Its better if you include in your answer, whats wrong you have done in SQL query ... so that future user will understand whats the problem?

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName No, that information isn't useful in the slightest bit. The "bad SQL query change" was a one-off occasion. Future "Oops" screens will, with overwhelming probability, not be related to this at all.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName yep, Chris is right - this was a missing `Option()` wrap on an `Optimize For` clause I *thought* I had tested but was hitting another code path. Nothing special this time - I try and include the interesting bits of fail in the answers if relevant :)

Comment: @Chris :- Yes I agree with you on that...current issue is not always the reason  for"Oops" screen. but as Nick already give some glimpse of it...thats fine..